# Why am I getting "unsupported network unix" with Cloud SQL Proxy, when I'm specifying TCP?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm having issues when trying to connect to my Cloud SQL instance.  I created a SQL Server instance, downloaded the cloud sql proxy, and everything seems to start to connect, but I keep getting the following error:

> errors parsing config:
>
> invalid "instance-connection-name": unsupported network: unix

I'm specifying the tcp port to use, but it still complains about UNIX.  Here is the command I'm using when trying to connect (I replaced the actual instance connection name for privacy/security):

```
./cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=[instance-connection-name]=tcp:3306
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Confirm that your TCP port for your SQL Server should be 1433, not 3306? 3306 is MySQL default.

Comment: Hi.  I've actually tried that port as well, but get the same error.

Comment: K good, just eliminating the easy stuff. :) How sure are you the service account you're using has the right permissions to access Cloud SQL? (it could be a bad error message). It should have the `cloudsql.instances.connect` permission, which would come with the `cloudsql.client|editor|admin` role when you created the service account.

Comment: Also, what output do you get when the proxy starts? Should see `using credential file for authentication` with the service account email, and then `Listening on 127.0.0:1433 for <instance name>` and finally `Ready for new connections`. And when you try to connect, the process where the proxy is running, is that what gives you the error message? Or do you get the error message from where you're connecting to the proxy from? Is there additional output you get from the proxy process?

Comment: Great points.  I'm actually not using a service account.  I'm just using my SDK credentials.  When I run the gcloud auth command, it authenticates me.  But when I run the cloud_sql_proxy command, I get this:

PS C:\downloads\googlecloud> ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances= <instance>:us-central1:mh-analytics-sql =tcp:1433
2020/02/10 10:22:25 Using gcloud's active project: [<instance>]
2020/02/10 10:22:31 errors parsing config:
        invalid "<instance>:us-central1:mh-analytics-sql": unsupported network: unix

Comment: When you run `gcloud init` to establish creds, confirm that the project and region match where your Cloud SQL instance lives?

Comment: If they are, next step IMO would be to create a service account and try that route and see if that works. I feel like there's a disconnect somewhere between SDK creds and the instance. I walk through the credential stuff here in detail: https://medium.com/@GabeWeiss/cloud-sql-public-ip-allowlist-e2e375b4432d

Comment: sorry...that's what I meant...gcloud auth.  It authenticates.  I'll checkout your link, and try the service account.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I tried this and it works

1. Rename `cloud_sql_proxy_xxx` to `cloud_sql_proxy`
2. Open cmd in your `cloud_sql_proxy`'s location
3. Run the following command: `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[project:region:instance-name]=tcp:1433` without [ ]

Answer (score 0):

From [Connecting to a Cloud SQL for SQL Server using a Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy):

**Depending on your language and environment, you can start the proxy using either TCP sockets or Unix sockets.**

**TCP sockets:**

1. Copy your instance connection name from the Instance details page

   For example: `myproject:us-central1:myinstance`.
2. If you are using a service account to authenticate the proxy, note the location on your client machine of the private key file that was created when you created the service account.
3. Start the proxy.

Some possible proxy invocation strings:

a) Using Cloud SDK authentication:

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:1433`

The specified port must not already be in use, for example, by a local database server.

b) Using a service account and explicit instance specification (recommended for production environments):

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:1433 \
                  -credential_file=<PATH_TO_KEY_FILE> &`

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I followed this document to the letter, and I'm still getting the same error.  I'm using a windows 10 machine, trying to connect to a SQL Server Instance.

Comment: Hi @JameyJameson, Windows and Cloud SQL Proxy works with TCP sockets. I would recommend you to do the following: 1. make sure that you changed the name of the Cloud SQL Proxy to `cloud_sql_proxy.exe` 2. run the following command: `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:1433`, leaving out the `./` part, as in the example for [Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#invocations). Let me know how it goes.